# Unexpected result of Clip

Tags: built-in-symbols, packed-arrays

A simple question. Here `Clip` works as documented:

```
Clip[0.5, {0, 0}, {0,1}]

(* 1 *)
```

Values larger than 0 are replaced with the integer 1. However, for a list we do not get integers:

```
lst=RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10}];
Clip[lst, {0,0}, {0,1}]

(* {0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,1.,0.,0.,1.} *)
```

whereas

```
Clip[#, {0,0},{0,1}]& /@ lst

(* {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1} *)
```

I am wondering if this is intended behaviour. As far as I can see, it is not documented. I have not observed this behaviour before. It  happens in 10.4 as well, but I do not have older versions to compare.

Comment: That is intended behavior. When operating on a packed array, `Clip` returns a packed array of the same type.

Comment: @ilian. Interesting, thanks. So it is not a bug. I think your comment should be included in the documentation.

Comment: @ilian But `Clip[RandomInteger[2, 10], {0., 0.}, {0., 1.}]` returns a packed array of reals.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Yes, my previous comment was not precise enough. It also matters whether the ranges can be packed and into what type. For example, `Clip[RandomInteger[2, 10], {0., 0.}, {0., 1}]` and `Clip[RandomReal[2, 10], {0., 0.}, {0., Infinity}]` do not return a packed result.

Comment: @ilian If you'll post a proper answer I'll delete mine.

Comment: another workaround: `Clip[lst, {0, 1}, {a, b}] /. {a -> 0, b -> 1}`

Answer (score 2):

Posting [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian)'s [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148480/unexpected-result-of-clip#comment398832_148480) as an answer,

> That is intended behavior. When operating on a packed array, `Clip` returns a packed array of the same type.

Checking:

```
lst = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10}];

lst2 = RandomInteger[2, 20];

Clip[lst, {0, 0}, {0, 1}]

Clip[lst2, {0, 0}, {0, 1}]

Clip[Developer`FromPackedArray@lst, {0, 0}, {0, 1}]
```

> ```
> {1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0.}
>
> {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}
>
> {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}
> ```

---

But `Clip[RandomInteger[2, 10], {0., 0.}, {0., 1.}]` returns a packed array of reals:

```
Clip[lst2, {0., 0.}, {0., 1.}]
% // Developer`PackedArrayQ
```

> ```
> {1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.}
>
> True
> ```

[ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian)'s [responce](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148480/unexpected-result-of-clip/148684#comment399125_148480):

> Yes, my previous comment was not precise enough. It also matters whether the ranges can be packed and into what type. For example, `Clip[RandomInteger[2, 10], {0., 0.}, {0., 1}]` and `Clip[RandomReal[2, 10], {0., 0.}, {0., Infinity}]` do not return a packed result.