# Any faster approach than Outer for my computation

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

`Outer` is slowing down considerably when the first argument is `Abs[#1 - #2]/Max[#1, #2]&`

```
Outer[List, Range[5000], Range[5000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.120091, Null} *)

Outer[Abs[#1 - #2]/Max[#1, #2]&, Range[5000], Range[5000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* ~ 59 seconds *)
```

Is there a faster way to perform the above computation? In the real problem I have two lists that are different and not `Range[5000]` i.e. the lists can be of different lengths.

Example with two small lists:

```
list1 = {6576.13, 7504.5, 6964., 7645.63, 5297.5, 6897.75, 4944.13, 8184.13, 
3426.75, 8722.75, 3683.63, 15344.4, 7026.25, 5677.63, 6872.88,
6050.5, 7948.63, 5095.13, 6335.25, 6024.25, 6508.88, 6961.63, 
8262.13, 4560.38, 7113.75, 7011., 9070.13, 5625.88, 7801., 6855.38, 
5973.25, 6164.75, 6115.75, 3886.13, 11967.4, 6606.13, 6223.5,
5576.38, 7855.88, 5616.38, 5946.88, 4750.25, 6162.25, 6539.88, 
5563.75, 7723.63, 6241.5, 3794.13, 6854.88, 8154., 4241.};

(* length is 50 *)

list2 = {3762.13, 7272.75, 7923.25, 7882.38, 4407., 7110., 6468.5, 7565.88, 
3117.25, 15918.8, 3753.5, 8801.25, 7120.13, 6643.63, 6565.5, 7537., 
6081.5, 6948.88, 7468.63, 6736., 7091.75, 7980., 5143.38, 7540.88, 
6754., 5746.13, 9075.63, 4536.5, 7873.75, 7106.5, 5127., 3809.25, 
5274.5, 6760.25, 7031.25, 7158.38, 7484.25, 5753.25, 6105.38, 
7084.63, 4866.88, 5690., 7179., 5572.88, 6209.13, 7820.25, 5432.5, 
2281.63, 3917.13, 4050.75};
(* length is 51 *)

Outer[Abs[#1 - #2]/Max[#1, #2]&,list1,list2];
```

This question is not a duplicate since it involves lists of different lengths.

Comment: see: [A quicker than outer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100551/5478), [Fastest way to calculate matrix of pairwise distances](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21861/5478)

Comment: @Kuba let me make the edit

Comment: @Kuba unfortunately the `DistanceMatrix` performs horribly with the custom `DistanceFunction` for `Range[5000]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to calculate matrix of pairwise distances](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21861/fastest-way-to-calculate-matrix-of-pairwise-distances)

Comment: @yohbs if you read the question carefully you will see that it is not a duplicate. Especially because this requires using a function on two different lists of different lengths. Something i have highlighted in the question.

Comment: The second one is doing rational arithmetic. I'd guess the `Compile` version in your response goes to machine real arithmetic, hence the speed gain. That at least is my guess for what causes the difference (I've not tried to verify it though).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau you are correct. it in fact uses machine real arithmetic

Comment: Have you tried `DistanceMatrix[list1, list2]/DistanceMatrix[list1, list2, DistanceFunction -> Max]`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be equivalent:

```
l = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 5000];
r = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 5000];

Function[left, Abs[left - r]/Clip[r, {left, ∞}]] /@ 
   l; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> 0.32

(Note that this is much faster for packed arrays of machine precision numbers instead of integers and fractions)

Comment: i like you approach @nikie. +1

Comment: Note that `Clip` is able to keep packed arrays packed: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148684/280

Answer (score 6):

You could try:

```
d[l1_, l2_] := With[{d = Outer[Plus, -l1, l2]}, Abs[d]/(Ramp[d] + l1)]
```

With your sample data:

```
r1 = d[list1, list2];
r2 = Outer[Abs[#1-#2]/Max[#1,#2]&, list1, list2];

r1===r2
```

> True

For some large lists:

```
l1 = RandomReal[1, 5000];
l2 = RandomReal[1, 5001];

d[l1, l2]; //AbsoluteTiming
Outer[List, l1, l2]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.483663, Null}
>
> {0.141301, Null}

So, not too much slower than your reference [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer) example.

Comment: thanks for this approach! +1

Comment: Would you kindly tell me how the performance of `Ramp` compares to `#*UnitStep[#] &`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard i tried and `Ramp` is only a tiny bit faster. 0.425 compared to 0.48 seconds for `l1` and `l2` above

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Here is a comparison: `In[1]:= With[{d = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10^7]}, {AbsoluteTiming[Ramp[d];], AbsoluteTiming[UnitStep[d] d;]}] Out[1]= {{0.022549, Null}, {0.056633, Null}}`

Comment: Thanks.  Nice to see a new function clearly outperforming old alternatives!

Answer (score 5):

This seems fairly snappy:

```
fn = With[{tup = Tuples[{#1, #2}]}, 
          Partition[Abs[Subtract @@ Transpose@tup]/(Max /@ tup), Length@#2]] &;
```

Use:

```
result= fn[list1, list2]
```

Comment: thank you very much +1 !

Answer (score 3):

so far i have found that `Compile` does  a pretty neat job in speeding up the computation

```
func = Compile[{{list1, _Integer, 1}, {list2, _Integer, 1}},
Outer[Abs[#1 - #2]/Max[#1, #2] &, list1, list2], 
CompilationTarget -> "C"];


func[Range@5000, Range@5000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.61639, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

On my computer this is 6 times faster:

```
L1 = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 5000];
L2 = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 5000];
Map[Abs[L2 - #] &, L1]/Outer[Max, L1, L2]
```

The following is 3.6 times faster than the code above

```
sz = Length[L2] + 1;
Map[(u[[Most[#[[;; First[FirstPosition[#, sz]]]]] &[
  Ordering[Append[u = L2, #]]]]] = #; Abs[L2 - #]/u) &, L1]
```

And in both cases the `Length` of `L1` should be less than that of `L2`

Comment: actually during computation we do not know whether `L1` is smaller than `L2`

Comment: on the other hand you can generalize this using an `If` statement to assign the bigger list to one variable and smaller to another to maintain consistency.

Comment: you might want to check the efficiency on say `L1 = L2 = Range[5000]`. it gives 30 seconds and 21 seconds  respectively on my PC.